# How to use split() command in order to calculate specific words in a txt

Tags: python

I have a `txt` file from which I want to export all the words that start with **'F'** or **'f'** with the use of list comprehension and command `split()`.

```
count = []
with open('data.txt','r') as myfile:
    count = [line for line in myfile.split() if (line[0]=='F' or line[0]=='f')]
print(count)
```

And I take the following error

> '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'

Thus is there any other way to use list comprehension and the command split in order to take the desired result ??

Comment: And then something like `line.startswith().lower() == 'f'`.

Comment: you don't need split() at all in this case. you can iterate over `myfile` directly, without reading whole file in memory with `myfile.readlines()`

Comment: @S3DEV ```line.startswith().lower() == 'f' ``` will consider also the capital letter cases ??

Comment: @G1l2A - Yes.  The lower() function converts the string to lower case, so you only need a single compare statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to split the line strings, not the file object (that you read strings from):

```
with open('data.txt','r') as myfile:
    count = [word
             for line in myfile
             for word in line.split()
             if word.lower().startswith('f')]
print(count)
```

The successive for-loops in the list-comprehension effectively flatten the file to a list of (f-) words. If you're not interested in the words themselves and just want the count, you could do

```
with open('data.txt','r') as myfile:
    # This works because bool inherits int, and True acts like 1, False like 0
    count = sum(word.lower().startswith('f')
                for line in myfile
                for word in line.split())
print(count)
```

Finally, if you want all the counts, use a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('data.txt','r') as myfile:
    count = Counter(word.lower()[0]
                    for line in myfile
                    for word in line.split())
print(count['f'])
```

Comment: So I read a line from myfile, then I split the words for that exact line and then run the if?? Thus it allows us to split inside a line but it doesn't allow us to split an object like myfile ??

Comment: Nice answer. I forgot about the `startswith` method.

Comment: Yes, since `myfile` is just that, a file, and `split()` is a method of `str` (what you read from the file). The decision if you should iterate line by line as in this example, or read the entire file and split its contents depends on for example the size of the file. Iterative methods allow processing large files without pulling them to memory at once.

Answer (score 0):

With this input file:

```
friday code floor funk
```

And this code:

```
f_words = []
with open('words.txt') as myfile:
    f_words = [word for word in myfile.read().split(" ") if word[0].lower() == 'f']
print(f_words)
```

I get this output:

```
['friday', 'floor', 'funk']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

***Python script***

```
count = []
with open('data.txt','r') as myfile:
    # remove len if you only need the words starting with `f`
    count = len([word for word in myfile.read().replace("\n"," ").split(" ") if word.lower()[0] == "f"])
print(count)
```

***Input file***

```
Sample line inside a File which is a File
Another line in the file with the word File
```

***Output***

```
4
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/RectangularAngelicTransformation)

You could replace `if word.lower()[0] == "f"` with `if word[0] == "f" or word[0] == "F"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also just concatenate the lines of your text and then use *split()* to iterate on the words.

```
lines = []
with open("text.txt", "r") as fin:
    lines = "".join(fin.readlines())
count = [w for w in lines.split() if w[0].lower() == 'f']
```